How to abort and destroy cytoscape instance immediately?
I found cytoscape will block the website when rendering, and the whole page has no respond until the rendering is finished or the page crashed, I can't call the cy.destroy() method in the progress.
I want to know that is there some methods can abort the process of rendering?
